# How can I read a whole file into a string variable

Tags: string, file, go

I have lots of small files, I don't want to read them line by line.

Is there a function in Go that will read a whole file into a string variable?

Answer (score 384, accepted):

**Edit**: the [`ioutil` package is now deprecated](https://pkg.go.dev/io/ioutil): "Deprecated: As of Go 1.16, the same functionality is now provided by package io or package os, and those implementations should be preferred in new code. See the specific function documentation for details." Because of Go's compatibility promise, `ioutil.ReadMe` is safe, but [@openwonk's updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38811255) is better for new code.

---

Old answer:

Use [`ioutil.ReadFile`](http://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadFile):

```
func ReadFile(filename string) ([]byte, error)
```

> ReadFile reads the file named by filename and returns the contents. A successful call
> returns err == nil, not err == EOF. Because ReadFile reads the whole file, it does not treat
> an EOF from Read as an error to be reported.

You will get a `[]byte` instead of a `string`. It can be converted if *really* necessary:

```
s := string(buf)
```

Comment: Then for constructing the final string result, you can use append() to accumulate the data in a single byte slice as you read each file, then convert the accumulated byte slice to the final string result.  Alternatively you might like bytes.Join.

Comment: Show us how to convert it then... The question doesn't ask for a byte array.

Comment: Using this to open a html file and I find a new line is appended after every line which is messing us some of my formatting. Is there any way to avoid that?

Comment: The golang is strongly typed. Conversion is _really_ necessary if you need type string rather than []byte. Happily _string(bytes)_ gets the job done.

Comment: Ioutil is deprecated now us os for file handling.

Answer (score 142):

If you just want the content as `string`, then the simple solution is to use the `ReadFile` function from the `io/ioutil` package. This function returns a slice of `bytes` which you can easily convert to a `string`.

**Go 1.16 or later**

Replace `ioutil` with `os` for this example.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    b, err := os.ReadFile("file.txt") // just pass the file name
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(b) // print the content as 'bytes'

    str := string(b) // convert content to a 'string'

    fmt.Println(str) // print the content as a 'string'
}
```

**Go 1.15 or earlier**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
)

func main() {
    b, err := ioutil.ReadFile("file.txt") // just pass the file name
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(b) // print the content as 'bytes'

    str := string(b) // convert content to a 'string'

    fmt.Println(str) // print the content as a 'string'
}
```

Comment: Ioutil is deprecated now

Comment: Thanks @PirateKing. Updated answer using `os` package.

Comment: Thanks @openwonk, can you move the Go 1.16 example to the top of the answer to make sure it's noticed?

Answer (score 25):

I think the best thing to do, if you're really concerned about the efficiency of concatenating all of these files, is to copy them all into the same bytes buffer.

```
buf := bytes.NewBuffer(nil)
for _, filename := range filenames {
  f, _ := os.Open(filename) // Error handling elided for brevity.
  io.Copy(buf, f)           // Error handling elided for brevity.
  f.Close()
}
s := string(buf.Bytes())
```

This opens each file, copies its contents into buf, then closes the file.  Depending on your situation you may not actually need to convert it, the last line is just to show that buf.Bytes() has the data you're looking for.

Comment: Hi,will io.Copy overwrite buf's content ? And what's the capacity of buf  ? Thanks.

Comment: Copy won't overwrite, it will just keep adding to buf, and buf will grow as much as it needs to accomodate the new data.

Comment: The buf has an "infinite" capacity. It will continue to expand as more data is added. ioutil.Readfile will allocate a buffer that is big enough to fit the complete file and not need to reallocate.

Comment: Does using a bytebuffer really improve performance compared to simply appending it to the slice(/array)? What about memory? How big is the difference?

Answer (score 20):

This is how I did it:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "os"
  "bytes"
  "log"
)

func main() {
   filerc, err := os.Open("filename")
   if err != nil{
     log.Fatal(err)
   }
   defer filerc.Close()

   buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
   buf.ReadFrom(filerc)
   contents := buf.String()

   fmt.Print(contents) 

}
```

Comment: While ioutil.ReadFile is more concise and thus is preferable when the file isn't already open, buf.ReadFrom() works in cases where you are already given an open file, so it is a good second answer.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [strings.Builder](//godocs.io/strings#Builder):

```
package main

import (
   "io"
   "os"
   "strings"
)

func main() {
   f, err := os.Open("file.txt")
   if err != nil {
      panic(err)
   }
   defer f.Close()
   b := new(strings.Builder)
   io.Copy(b, f)
   print(b.String())
}
```

Or if you don't mind `[]byte`, you can use
[os.ReadFile](//godocs.io/os#ReadFile):

```
package main
import "os"

func main() {
   b, err := os.ReadFile("file.txt")
   if err != nil {
      panic(err)
   }
   os.Stdout.Write(b)
}
```

Comment: As the @Cerise Limón's answer [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64830717/704244): _"You can improve the strings.Builder example by growing the builder to the size of the file before reading"_; we could `fi, _ := f.Stat()` `b.Grow(int(fi.Size()))` before `io.Copy(b, f)`

Answer (score 2):

For **Go 1.16 or later** you can read file at compilation time.

Use the //go:embed directive and the [embed](https://tip.golang.org/pkg/embed/) package in [Go 1.16](https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.16)

For example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    _ "embed"
)

//go:embed file.txt
var s string

func main() {
    fmt.Println(s) // print the content as a 'string'
}
```

Comment: Good comment, but not an answer.

Comment: What's confusing, //go:embed is not actually a comment. At least I don't think so.

Comment: This is a great comment, exactly what I was looking for!