# PHP file_get_contents in Go lang

Tags: php, go, file-get-contents

I'm new to Golang. Actually I'm a PHP developer.

I need `file_get_contents` function in Golang.

Can you please provide code for this or suggest Golang library for my requirement.

**Note:** Keep in mind [`file-get-contents`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.file-get-contents.php) does more than just "read a file".

Comment: Do what everyone else does and [use the packages page](http://golang.org/pkg/). [Hint](http://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/13514184/6309

Comment: @VonC what about `http`

Comment: Right, or file section.

Comment: @Chandra Why don't you stick to PHP?....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think there is one unique golang function as versatile as [`file-get-contents.php`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.file-get-contents.php).

- For reading a all file: "[How Can i read a whole file into a string variable in golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13514395/6309)" (yes, [`io/ioutil/#ReadFile`](http://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadFile))
- For reading an http page: `http.Get` (see [this example](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#example_Get))

  ```
  res, err := http.Get("http://www.google.com/robots.txt")
  if err != nil {
      log.Fatal(err)
  }
  robots, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
  res.Body.Close()
  ```
- For reading part of a file: see "[Go by Example: Reading Files](https://gobyexample.com/reading-files)"

> You’ll often want more control over how and what parts of a file are read.
>   For these tasks, start by Opening a file to obtain an [os.File](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#File) value.

```
f, err := os.Open("/tmp/dat")
check(err)

# You can also Seek to a known location in the file and Read from there.

o2, err := f.Seek(6, 0)
check(err)
b2 := make([]byte, 2)
n2, err := f.Read(b2)
check(err)
fmt.Printf("%d bytes @ %d: %s\n", n2, o2, string(b2))
```