# Would like to work with same file content passed to library, without opening file twice

Tags: go, io

I am using the library `gopkg.in/freeeve/pgn.v1` to read text files in a "pgn" format specific to chess games.  It uses `text/scanner` under the hood of its `NewPGNScanner`.

Unfortunately it provides no easy way to get back the input it takes in from the pgn file, so I am separately pulling in all the file contents into a buffer, which I convert to a string slice, to work with simultaneously with `NewPGNScanner` (I am well aware of the potential memory issues but the files are small, and I unshift from the slice on every pass over the game contents, thereby continually decreasing the memory consumed):

```
func main() {
    f, err := os.Open("../before_fide_master.pgn")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    buf.ReadFrom(f)
    allPgnBlocks := strings.Split(buf.String(),"\n\n")
    var gamePgnBlocks []string

    // f, err = os.Open("../before_fide_master.pgn")

    pgnContent := pgn.NewPGNScanner(f)

    for pgnContent.Next() {
        game, err := pgnContent.Scan()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        if len(game.Moves) >= 1 {
            gamePgnBlocks, allPgnBlocks = allPgnBlocks[0:2], allPgnBlocks[2:]
        }

        fmt.Printf("%v\n\n", gamePgnBlocks[0])
        fmt.Printf("%v\n\n", gamePgnBlocks[1])
    }
}
```

Note the commented out line.  Without it, no iteration occurs over `for pgnContent.Next()`; it needs to be commented in for my program to proceed in the way that I'd like.  So it seems that `buf.ReadFrom(f)` is interfering with the `text/scanner` being used under the hood by the library.

I have googled without finding anything quite on point.  This accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13514395/34806 calls for using `ioutil.ReadFile` which of course reads the file yet again -- I actually based my approach on an less up-voted answer for the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43449991/34806

I've also started reading the docs at https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer without honing in on how exactly I might achieve some sort of "rewind" without having to call `os.Open` on the file a second time.  I think it might be in there though, and I think this will make a useful Q&A for anybody who has a similar need in the future, thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using `Seek` on the opened file?

Comment: @mkopriva Thanks, I can now answer this myself

Comment: There is also [`TeeReader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#TeeReader) for multiple concurrent readers.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the simplest solution, after reading bytes from the file with `buf.ReadFrom(f)`, is as follows:

```
// f, err = os.Open("../before_fide_master.pgn")
f.Seek(0, 0)
```

Thanks to mkopriva.  I googled and found the `f.Seek(0, 0)` technique here: https://gobyexample.com/reading-files

Comment: Note that reading the file once, seeking back, and reading again *could* get you *different* data, if the underlying file has changed between the two read operations. Some OSes prohibit this, some allow it, and on those that allow it, the file might well *not* be changed, so if it's not a problem and that's the simple solution, go with it. :-)