# strings.Builder memory usage

Tags: string, go, memory, bytebuffer

Using this file ([data file](//speedtest.lax.hivelocity.net/100mb.file)):

```
package main

import (
   "io/ioutil"
   "time"
)

func main() {
   ioutil.ReadFile("100mb.file")
   time.Sleep(time.Duration(time.Minute))
}
```

Showed memory usage for me of 107 MB. With this similar file:

```
package main

import (
   "bytes"
   "os"
   "time"
)

func read(path_s string) (bytes.Buffer, error) {
   buf_o := bytes.Buffer{}
   open_o, e := os.Open(path_s)
   if e != nil {
      return buf_o, e
   }
   buf_o.ReadFrom(open_o)
   open_o.Close()
   return buf_o, nil
}

func main() {
   read("100mb.file")
   time.Sleep(time.Duration(time.Minute))
}
```

Memory usage went to 273 MB. Finally this similar file:

```
package main

import (
   "io"
   "os"
   "strings"
   "time"
)

func read(path_s string) (strings.Builder, error) {
   str_o := strings.Builder{}
   open_o, e := os.Open(path_s)
   if e != nil {
      return str_o, e
   }
   io.Copy(&str_o, open_o)
   open_o.Close()
   return str_o, nil
}

func main() {
   read("100mb.file")
   time.Sleep(time.Duration(time.Minute))
}
```

Memory usage went to 432 MB. I tried to be careful and close files where
possible. Why is the memory usage so high for the second example, and especially
the final example? Can I change something so that they are closer to the first
example?

Comment: `ReadFrom` will grow the buffer as needed, so it may end up over-allocating more than you need. Perhaps use `ReadFile` and convert to string https://stackoverflow.com/a/13515526/11746212

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ioutil.ReadFile("100mb.file")` gets the size of the file, allocates a `[]byte` that size and slurps the bytes up into that slice.

`buf_o.ReadFrom(open_o)` allocates an initial `[]byte` of some size and reads into that slice.  If there's more data in the reader than space in the slice, then the function allocates a larger slice, copies existing data to that slice and reads more. This repeats until EOF.

The function ioutil.ReadFile uses bytes Buffer.ReadFrom internally.  Take a look at the ioutil.ReadFile implementation to see how to improve direct use of the bytes.Buffer. A synopsis of the logic is this:

```
var buf bytes.Buffer

// Open file
f, err := os.Open(path)
if err != nil {
    return &buf, err
}
defer f.Close()

// Get size.
fi, err := f.Stat()
if err != nil {
    return &buf, err
}

// Grow to size of file plus extra slop to ensure no realloc.
buf.Grow(int(fi.Size()) + bytes.MinRead)

_, err := buf.ReadFrom(f)
return &buf, err
```

The strings.Builder example reallocates the internal buffer several times as in the bytes.Buffer example. In addition, io.Copy allocates a buffer. You can improve the strings.Builder example by [growing the builder](https://godoc.org/strings#Builder.Grow) to the [size](https://godoc.org/os#FileInfo.Size) of the [file](https://godoc.org/os#File.Stat) before reading.

Here's the code for strings.Builder:

```
var buf strings.Builder

// Open file
f, err := os.Open(path)
if err != nil {
    return &buf, err
}
defer f.Close()

// Get size.
fi, err := f.Stat()
if err != nil {
    return &buf, err
}

buf.Grow(int(fi.Size()))

_, err = io.Copy(&buf, f)
return &buf, err
```

io.Copy or some other code using an extra buffer is required because strings.Builder does not have a ReadFrom method. The strings.Builder type does not have a ReadFrom method because that method can leak a reference to the backing array of the internal slice of bytes.

Comment: If a `string` is needed, I noticed that `io/ioutil#ReadFile` with `string()`
actually doubles the memory usage, while `strings#Builder.String` with
`strings#Builder.Grow` has no memory hit. Thanks!

Comment: @StevenPenny  The strings.Builder type uses the [unsafe package](https://godoc.org/unsafe)  to convert the internal `[]byte` to a `string` with no allocations.  If you don't mind the use of the unsafe package in your own code, convert the byte slice `p` returned from ioutil.ReadFile to a string with `*(*string)(unsafe.Pointer(&p))`.

Comment: @StevenPenny You say "if a string is needed". Is your actual question about reading a file to a `string` in the most memory efficient way?

Comment: I guess it depends. In the process of posting this question, and reinforced by your answer, I discovered that in many case memory use doubles when you convert from Byte slice to String. So Ideally I would like to just have a String returned, but with this knowledge, it seems better to just take the Byte slice, cut it down as needed, and then only convert the needed part

Answer (score 1):

Using suggestion from [Muffin Top](//stackoverflow.com/questions/64830650#64830717), I took my second example and added this
directly before the call to `ReadFrom`:

```
stat_o, e := open_o.Stat()
if e != nil {
   return buf_o, e
}
buf_o.Grow(bytes.MinRead + int(stat_o.Size()))
```

and the memory went down to 107 MB, basically the same as the first example.